# How to insert array of object to table with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have array of object at raw Postman. and i want that insert to my table. i have confusion to make the controller and model. this is my code

postman [My postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORXoA.png)

My controller code :

```
module.exports = {
    postOrder: async (request, response) => {
        try {
            const setData = {
                // id_history : request.body,
                id_product : request.body.orders.id_product,
                product_name : request.body.orders.product_name,
                image : request.body.orders.image,
                ppn : request.body.orders.ppn,
                price : request.body.orders.price
            }
            const result = await postOrder(setData)
            return helper.response(response, 201, "Create Category Success", result);
        } catch (error) {
            return helper.response(response, 400, "Bad Request", error);
        }
    }
}
```

My model code :

```
module.exports = {
    postOrder: (setData) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query("INSERT INTO order SET ?", setData, (error, result) => {
                console.log(result)
                if(!error) {
                    const newResult = {
                        ...setData
                    }
                    resolve(newResult)
                } else {
                    reject(new Error(error))
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if the explanation is not clear. please let me know if the explanation is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to lean towards building the query with placeholders and then passing in the values, it may work your way but I'm not sure it would be a prepared query.

```
module.exports = {
  postOrder: setData => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
      let keys = Object.keys(setData)
      let values = Object.values(setData)
      
      let sql = `
        INSERT INTO order (
          ${keys.join(',')}
        ) VALUES (
          ${keys.fill('?', 0, keys.length).join(',')}
        )
      `
      
      connection.query(sql, values, (error, result) => {
        if (error) reject(new Error(error))

        resolve(orderData)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: i am sorry, but my code doesnt work. are my code already correct ?? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTY3I.png

Comment: just copy and paste it, the query is wrong `${keys.join}` etc